# Mongoose limiting queries doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to limit my results

```
    items.find(function(err, theItems){
        if(err) res.send(err)
        res.json(theItems);
    });
```

I searched and I should do .limit and with certain versions it should be combined with sort and exec etc etc.

However it's not working. I just can't find an answer on something simple like this :/

Also, out of all the documentation that I've been reading and learning from for the past 2 months, mongoose's is by far the most difficult to understand.
Is there a good place somewhere to learn mongoose from ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future you should show the code that *isn't* working so we can help diagnose the issue.

in mongoose you chain together parts of the query until you're ready to execute it. you can do:

`items.find().sort({field: 1}).limit(5).exec(function(err, theItems) ...`

Comment: ok ok Thanks I should have posted the wrong code. wanna know what I did wrong? I'm literally laughing now. i did find.limit instead of find() :D
thanks man

Comment: np. remember to select it as the correct answer if it did work ;)